# updateOne is not working on saving the array in an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Database -

```
{   
    _id: some_id,
    people: {
      person: []   
  } 
}
```

Query-

```
const result = await Model.updateOne(
          { _id: _id }, 
          { $set: { "people.person": [{name: some_name, age: 21}] }}
        );
```

So when I console the result--
// result - { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }.
This clearly is not updating the document.
Can Someone tell me where I'm going wrong.
Thanks

Edit: All the things are correct here. Just I haven't got the people object in Schema that's why it was not working.

Comment: Does https://mongoplayground.net/p/nDCYvbycj8x this help you?

Comment: I think you need to push an person object in person array just use `$push` instead of `$set` look at this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D51vuwDF8pp)

Comment: Thanks @varman for the directing me to playground.

Comment: @turivishal Actually from the frontend I'm sending the whole array which I need to update in mongoDB. That's why I am using $set.

Comment: Okay so your updated query looks good, you can check other possibilities of failure, i checked your response `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`, its not matching any record, so the problem in your query part means `{ _id: _id }` verify proper input id, console it, verify it in db and last convert it to objectid and then try.

Comment: Okay. So I am logging it. And everything is fine. And I am not converting id to ObjectId. Is that necessary?

Comment: Hey @turivishal, I got the query working. Turns out there was no schema of the people defined. So I just added people to the schema and it got working. Thanks for the help.